# How to send information only if the internet connectivity is enabled?

Tags: android

With this method i know when the user is connected or not.

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = 
         (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

in my application when the user press send it will upload some data to the server, if there is not conectivity it will say "we will try to send it later" but how i can check the internet status  and only  when the connectivity is on, send the information?

Comment: You already have the method that checks for a connection, why not simply call it?

Comment: make the service for this..and check the internet connectivity in that or either can use receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use an `IntentService` to handle all of your data uploads. Have it check for connectivity with the method you have - if connected, upload the data otherwise store it (use `SharedPreferences` or a database).

Second create a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it in the manifest with the following `<intent-filter>`...

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />"
</intent-filter>
```

NOTE: You will need the following permissions...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

In the `onReceive(...)` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` have it check to see if any data is pending and, if there is, have it start the `IntentService` to send the data.

Also, use `Notifications` created by the `IntentService` to give feedback to the user.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no internet connectivity detected why don't you alert the user that the message will be sent when they connect. Run a background process, or service that checks periodically if the user is connected, and when they are a method that sends the data is run.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

If you want a additional example : http://www.androidsnippets.com/have-internet

The site in the first link(AndroidHive.info) is a newbies best friend.All the tuts provide dl able source code that is almost fool proof and very well written/documented. There is alot you can do just hacking together different pieces from his tuts into something unique. Best way to learn imo

Comment: thanks, but how i create a interval of time to check every 5 minutes, or there is any way to automatically call this method when the connectivity is enabled?